# Installing sysbench on redhat 7 - 404 not found

Tags: redhat, yum

I have redhat 7 and I've been trying to get sysbench installed and following the instructions here:

https://wiki.mikejung.biz/Sysbench#Installing_Sysbench

```
yum install http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install sysbench
```

But it throws an error of 404 in the terminal and I tried other solutions that are given via google. How can this be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After trying a bunch of different solutions. It seems that everyone is referencing the url:

http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

But it doesnt exists anymore as of 2016-December. What I did was remove the .rpm file at the end and just goto the url:

http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release

From there I was able to get the latest updated one which is this:

https://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/percona-release/redhat/percona-release-0.1-4.noarch.rpm

Now you should be able to do this on redhat 7 as of 2016-Dec:

```
wget https://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/percona-release/redhat/percona-release-0.1-4.noarch.rpm
yum install <rpm you downloaded>
yum install sysbench
```

Comment: Bravo for working through this and posting an answer. All too many people mindlessly read step-by-step tutorials, run into simple issues like this, and end up posting their question here, when 5 minutes of troubleshooting would have fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, but as a newbie, we tend to just copy and paste in the beginning without understanding whats going on. We can all argue and get frustrated of why didn't the person just do something that seems so simple to a novice user, but in the end we all started somewhere. Some were smarter than others to figure it ourselves, but *many* still need some hand holding every now and then. If it was this easy then anyone can do what we do, but its not.

Comment: Also 5 minutes of troubleshooting might be for you or me, but to a newbie it could take them hours or even days for something so simple such as this. It might not make any sense to the more experienced user, but this is something a more experienced person need to show empathy for.

Comment: I'm trying to give you a compliment here. If you don't care to accept it, I guess that's fine.

Comment: Yes, I thank you for it. I'm just ranting about the situation about simple questions that users asks every now and then. It seems obviously easy to some of us and we like to troll on them for not research properly. Either way thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the 0.0-1x86_64 version, it's **[here](https://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.0-1/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm)**

```
yum install https://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.0-1/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install sysbench
```

All the differents versions can be found [here](https://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/) for redhat distributions.
And for others distro : https://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/